# How to handle missing screens in Chrome

Tags: appium-android, python-appium

I'm facing a problem while executing my test cases for a native app. The thing is when I launch **Chrome** then the flow is like Accept & Continue > Next > No Thanks > url to my web app.

Sometimes the Next screen is missing and the **No Thanks** screen is displayed.

I tried using if-else, and or conditions but they didn't work out for me

```
from appium import webdriver
from time import sleep

desired_cap = {
    "platformName": "Android",
    "platformVersion": "8.1",
    "deviceName": "emulator-5554",
    "appPackage": "com.android.chrome",
    "appActivity": "com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main",
    "automationName": "Appium",
    "appReset": "true"}

driver = webdriver.Remote('http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub', desired_cap)
driver.implicitly_wait(30)

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//android.widget.Button[@text='ACCEPT & CONTINUE']").click()
choices = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//android.widget.Button[@text='NEXT'] or //android.widget.Button[@text='NO THANKS'][1]").click()
```

Comment: everytime you are relaunching the app ?

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
from appium import webdriver
from time import sleep

desired_cap = {
    "platformName": "Android",
    "platformVersion": "8.1",
    "deviceName": "emulator-5554",
    "appPackage": "com.android.chrome",
    "appActivity": "com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main",
    "automationName": "Appium",
    "appReset": "true"}

driver = webdriver.Remote('http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub', desired_cap)
driver.implicitly_wait(30)

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//android.widget.Button[@text='ACCEPT & CONTINUE']").click()
time.sleep(4)

try :

     driver.find_element_by_xpath([@text='NEXT']).click()


except : 
       pass

driver.find_element_by_xpath(Button[@text='NO THANKS']).click()
```

Comment: Thanks for the update and don't you think that adding sleep again and again in the scripts is not recommended though

Comment: Yes, I'm using an emulator and the app is relaunched every time. Is there any way that the tests should start from the landing page because in current case **driver.get("www.gsmarena.com")** is not working for me

Comment: **try** will work with **except** or **finally** block

Comment: it doesn't work as there is no exception defined for the except block

Comment: edited it should work now . it will try for next button. if it doesnt occur it ill pass to the no thanks button and as i dont have xpath i have kept random xpath.